# Spring project getting exceptions

Tags: java, spring

I have tried a spring(3.1.0) project for the first time,but it gives me runtime errors.I have added log4j but still error occurs.and the `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory` is deprecated too.
please help me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.<init>(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.<init>(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractBeanFactory.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:66)
    at com.vehicle.SpringDemoApp.main(SpringDemoApp.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more<br/>
```

this is what i got

Comment: Can you post the detailed Exception and the related code?

Answer (score 1):

You need apache commons-logging in the classpath. Log4j is not commons-logging.

Comment: thank you,i corrected my project but now no output at all.why org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory is deprecated?

Comment: The javadoc says: as of Spring 3.1 in favor of DefaultListableBeanFactory and XmlBeanDefinitionReader

Answer (score 0):

download commons logging jar from
http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi

Answer (score 0):

You can check which class is in which Opensource (OSS) library [here](http://www.jarvana.com/).

If you are using Maven, you can try adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
   <classifier>api</classifier>
</dependency>
```